# how to display a child variable with parameter

Tags: powershell, shell, variables, powershell-3.0

greet
i wrote an simple PowerShell script to store simple massage in variable ,and display the massage with parameter , it work pretty well.
but when i add multiple value in the variable [image: multiple varible]

i can't call the specific variable with parameter

code :

```
[Parameter()]
[string]
$ParameterName.$var = "".Get-Variable -name $ParameterName  -ValueOnly
```

and call it like this : [image: help.ps1 var]

it should display $var's value

problem is can i display the variable with multiple value ?
for example

[image: multiple variable]

how can i display the $var[0] with the same method ?

Comment: The screenshot(s) you've shown contain a _hashtable_ literal. You need to index into it by key, eg. `$web['vpn']`

Comment: Please add your code as text instead of pictures.

Answer (score -1):

```
    [CmdletBinding()]
param (
    
        [Parameter()]
    
        [string]
    
        $ParameterName).
    $display  =
    "help.ps -powershell
    
              #powershell 
              #spd 
              #wpe
              #pot 
              #web
    "
    
    
    Get-Variable -name $ParameterName  -ValueOnly  
                                             
    $parameterName = Get-Variable -name $ParameterName  -ValueOnly
    
    
    start $ParameterName
```

Comment: i  store the password or software commandline in the variable,it work when i call it in terminal ,but i want to add a multiple value Variable and call the child-value with the same method for example   $web =@{vpn ='C:\Users\34683\Documents\website\vpn.rtf';
   GFW = 'C:\Users\34683\Documents\website\GFW.docx';
}

Comment: It's commendable that you want to share a solution, but (a) your question is unclear and (b) the code in your answer is broken.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).